# Can I use openssl cli tools to generate SCEP request message?

Tags: pki, scep

I'm trying to request a certifiacte through SCEP service. I used openssl to generate key and CSR file. But I don't find a way to generate PKImessage send to scep server. Is it possible to use openssl cli to generate the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is 'No'.

However, you could use `sscep` which is a free command-line tool that will send the request to your SCEP server.

It's available from https://github.com/certnanny/sscep.  A complied version for Windows is available from [here](http://secadmins.com/index.php/ndes-scep-windows-test-tool/) and I believe it's available for RPM based Linux distros too.